# Editing a whole column in a Microsoft List

Tags: list, sharepoint

When you are new to an application, you are yet to discover all of the tricks that you can do to make your tasks easier and less time consuming.  This, for example, was the case for me with Excel.  But now I know how to do things that was once a mystery.  Now I am faced with the same sort of thing with Microsoft List.

The task I am facing is to either replace all of the cells in one column of my Lists or simply remove all the quotation marks in the cell.  If I can select the whole column to copy, and then later paste the column, that would be good enough.  This is because I can make the change in the text data in Textpad or Notepad++

So, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to implement it directly in Lists. You can export the data in the list to excel, and then search, replace and save it in excel. Then import the data into Lists.